# Keyboard/Touchpad Unrecognized by X11/Xfce4

Tags: drivers, xorg, freebsd, keyboard, touchpad

It is recognized by FreeBSD in terminal or command mode.

The lines in `Xorg.0.log` are:

```
9102.753    config/udev: Adding input device AT keyboard (/dev/input/event5)
9102.753    AT Keyboard: Applying InputClass “Evdev Keyboard”
9102.753    AT Keyboard: Applying InputClass “KeyboardDefaults”
9102.754    No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
9102.754    This device may have been added with another device file.
9102.754    config/udev: Adding input device Syn PS/2 Synaptics Touchpad  (/dev/input/event6)
9102.754    No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
9102.754    This device may have been added with another device file.
```

What drivers do I have to download?  What should my "InputClass" block look like?

Just out of curiosity, how come my keyboard works in command mode, but not in GUI mode?

I'd really appreciate if you could help me out with this problem.  I've been struggling with it for quite a while.

EDIT:
Contents of /etc/rc.conf:

ifconfig_bfe0="inet 192.168.XXX.XXX netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.X"
defaultrouter="XXX.XXX.XXX.X"
ssh_enable="YES"
ntpdate_enable="YES"
dumpdev="AUTO"
apache24_enable="yes"
mysql_enable="yes"
dbus_enable="YES"

Comment: Seek for help in `freebsd-x11` or `freebsd-ports` mailing lists.

Comment: I have.  What would be the driver most likely to work for an 2007 laptop (Dell Vostro 1000).  And what would be the right settings to use in the InputClass section in the xorg.conf.d directory?  The keyboard does work in plain console mode, so why wouldn't it work under X?

Comment: Did you mess with xorg.conf? You shouldn't need one. Were you following the handbook?

Comment: I did add some .conf files in there.  Should I remove them?

Comment: By the way, is there a well known driver that I should install?

Comment: I just tried plugging in a USB keyboard and mouse and both of them failed to work, too.  I just I'd tell you.  Perhaps it could reveal something about why the built-in keyboard and track don't get recognized by X11. (Both the built-in and USB keyboards work in the console).

Comment: I deleted the .conf files in xorg.conf.d, but still no luck.  I just updated my original post with mt /etc/rc.conf ...